# How do I perform a Union in Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to perform a union operation in Dataflow.  Is there sample code for taking the union of two PCollections in Dataflow?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to combine Flatten() with RemoveDuplicates() like so.  Depending on whether you want the disjoint union or set-theoretic union, the RemoveDuplicates call can be omitted:

```
PCollection<String> pc1 = ...;
PCollection<String> pc2 = ...;
PCollection<String> union = PCollectionList.of(pc1).and(pc2)
  .apply(Flatten.<String>pCollections())
  .apply(RemoveDuplicates.<String>create());
```

Comment: I wonder if it would be a good idea to add another RemoveDuplicates before the Flatten, in case there may be duplicates within each collection as well? i.e. PCollectionList.of(pc1.apply(RemoveDuplicates)).and(pc2.apply(RemoveDuplicates)) - or would the optimizer take care of this?

Comment: I think that "Flatten.<String>.create" should be "Flatten.<String>create"

Comment: @jkff The current optimizer would not take care of that, so you'd end up with two shuffles instead of one.

Comment: @SamMcVeety  Looks like "RemoveDuplicates" has changed to "Distinct" now. I am using Beam 2.4

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than two collections, a convenient solution is to fill a list of PCollection, make a PCollectionList based on that and the Flatten:

```
List<PCollection<TableRow>> tabs = new ArrayList<>();
/* ... fill tabs */
PCollectionList<TableRow> tabList = PCollectionList.of(tabs);
PCollection<TableRow> bigOne = tabList.apply(Flatten.<TableRow>create());
```

Hope this helps.